# SQLAlchemy SQLite compare dates

Tags: python, sqlite, date, sqlalchemy

Using SQLite, trying to get every `Appointment` that its `date + duration` is between `start_date` and `end_date`. When adding an appointment with a certain date and `13:00` as an hour and duration of `40`. Using `start_date` of 13:30 with duration of 40, it gives empty results (should find the aforementioned appointment).

```py
appointment_end_date = func.datetime(
    Appointment.date, f"+{Appointment.duration} MINUTES"
)
query = Appointment.query.filter(
    and_(start_date <= appointment_end_date, appointment_end_date <= end_date
    )
)
```

When changing `+{Appointment.duration}` to 40, it works. How can I use a column inside this expression?

Comment: You should perform the concatenation / formatting in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```py
func.datetime(func.strftime("%s", Appointment.date) + Appointment.duration * 60, "unixepoch")
```